# Mistake: undefined method `in_groups_of' for nil:NilClass

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-4

How insert in this code css class (stud)? Also I have a mistake:

```
undefined method `in_groups_of' for nil:NilClass
```

****View.rb****

```
    <% @students.in_groups_of(3) do |students| %>
          <tr>
            <% students.each do |student| %>
              <td><%= student.try(:display_name) %></td>
            <% end %>
          </tr>
        <% end %>

   #stud{
         padding:10 10 10 10;
         margin-left: 140px;
         border: 5px dotted;
         border-color: #ff5800;
         width: 350px;

     }
```

**Controller.rb**

```
def p
@students = Student.search(params[:search])
end
```

Comment: You're asking how to fix your ruby code? Or for the html/css to make a 3x3 layout?

Comment: The error is because `@students` is nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code you have:

```
<% @students.in_groups_of(3) do |students| %>
  <tr>
    <% students.each do |student| %>
      <td><%= student.try(:display_name) %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Needs to check if @students is nil:

```
<% if @students %>
  <% @students.in_groups_of(3) do |students| %>
    <tr>
      <% students.each do |student| %>
        <td id="stud"><%= student.try(:display_name) %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now if students is nil nothing is displayed.

Comment: And how to insert css code to td?

Comment: Well to apply `#stud` to the td you would need to add id="stud" to the  td tag.